# Error initializing array of struct element

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct, initialization

Good afternoon, for a school project i have to input and show the minutes of exercise for 30 days(1 month) of a client, the client is a struct which contains the array of days, when i initialize my program i initialize my vector of clients using:

```
//Struct
typedef struct{
char name[100];
int dayOfBirth;
int monthOfBirth;
int yearOfBirth;
char address[100];
int phone;
int iRSNumber;
float height;
float weight;
int exerMinutes[30];

}client;

client clients[100] = {};


//initialize struct of clients
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    strcpy(clients[i].name, "NULL");
    strcpy(clients[i].address, "NULL");
    clients[i].height = 0.0;
    clients[i].yearOfBirth = 0;
    clients[i].monthOfBirth = 0;
    clients[i].dayOfBirth = 0;
    clients[i].iRSNumber = 0;
    clients[i].weight = 0.0;
    clients[i].phone = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<30; j++){
        clients[i].exerMinutes[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Code to show the report:

```
system("cls");
printf("\nSHOW MONTHLY REPORT\n");
for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    if((i+1)%2==0 && i!=0){
        printf("day %2d: %3d min\n", i+1, Client->exerMinutes[i]);
    }else{
        printf("day %2d: %3d min\t\t", i+1, Client->exerMinutes[i]);
    }
}

printf("\n\nPress Enter to continue");
system("pause >nul /nobreak");
```

However the cycle for() to initialize the month array doesn't seems to work, because when i ask for the month report this is the output:

```
day  1: 100 min         day  2:   0 min
day  3:   0 min         day  4:   0 min
day  5:   0 min         day  6:   0 min
day  7:   0 min         day  8:   0 min
day  9:   0 min         day 10:   0 min
day 11:   0 min         day 12:   0 min
day 13:   0 min         day 14:   0 min
day 15:   0 min         day 16:   0 min
day 17:   0 min         day 18:   0 min
day 19:   0 min         day 20:   0 min
day 21:   0 min         day 22:   0 min
day 23:   0 min         day 24:   0 min
day 25:  10 min         day 26:   3 min
day 27: 1999 min                day 28: 1280070990 min
day 29:   0 min         day 30:   0 min
```

I would be thankful for any help and/or advice given.

Comment: You should provide the structure definition.

Comment: Compile with warnings: `warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces`, switch to `client clients[100] = {{0}};`

Comment: In addition to your struct definition, please also show us the code to print the data.

Comment: @Cid No need to use `malloc` when you declare it as array like `int a[30]`.

Comment: Since my teachers said that the amount of clients is 100, i didn't use malloc(); because i don't need a dynamic size array

Comment: What is `Client` in your code to print?

Comment: Just an aside, you could simply bzero your whole array and not bother setting names to "NULL" (handle that elsewhere) and avoid using a for() completely for efficiency sake.

Also note that `0.0` is a double, not a float. `0.0f`. Modern compilers are smart enough to handle this for you, but since you are learning, it's good to know this.

Comment: @Osiris the `Client` in my code to print, is a variable of the type `client` that i receive to print the information of its month

Comment: @CinderBiscuits thank you for the advice and after make the complete program i will look int efficiency but my since i'm in introduction to programming my teachers aren't looking for code efficiency because the project isn't big. Efficiency is an extra(Their words) but again, thanks for the advice and i'll look into it

Comment: If it is of type `client` then you should use `Client.exerMinutes[i]`.

Comment: @Osiris i use `Client->exerMinutes` because for the whole month submodule, add minutes, change them, printing month report i receive the `client` variable as reference

Comment: @CinderBiscuits i understand, however in my projects specifications i have to initialize my `name` and àddress` as "NULL", is there a way to use bzero only for éxerMinutes` array??

Comment: I can't find the error in this code. Please try to create a [mcve]. Also: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Sure, though you may wish to use `memset` as well, (`bzero` isn't actually standard C, it's ANSI) `memset(&clients[i].exerMinutes, 0, sizeof(clients[i].exerMinutes));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working perfectly, i.e. all the variables in the 'struct' are initialised with zeroes or whatever just as intended. I tried it with a few changes.

Problem is with these lines:

```
if((i+1)%2==0    &&    i!=0){
        printf("day    %2d:    %3d    min\n",    i+1,    Client->exerMinutes[i]);
}else{
        printf("day    %2d:    %3d    min\t\t",    i+1,    Client->exerMinutes[i]);
}
```

You've used pointer to structure "Client" but its not initialised and that's the reason you're getting unexpected results. Keep in mind that in this "Client", you've used a capital 'C'. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I realised I couldn't do using the client itself so I opted to send the full array of clients and the position of the client wanted so that I could modify that position on the array itself instead of modifying an instance of a client.